# Defining Lebesgue integral a different way

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have been defining the Lebesgue integral with the lower Lebesgue sum. Can I use this to prove that if $(X, S, \mu)$ is a measure space with $\mu(X) < \infty$ and if
$f : X → [0, \infty)$ is a bounded $S$ -measurable function. Then $\int f d \mu=\inf \left\{\sum_{j=1}^{m} \mu\left(A_{j}\right) \sup _{A_{j}} f: A_{1}, \ldots, A_{m} \text { is an } \mathcal{S} \text { -partition of } X\right\}$.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: By lower lebesgue sum do you mean step functions ?

Comment: $\begin{array}{l}\text { Suppose }(X, \mathcal{S}, \mu) \text { is a measure space, } f: X \rightarrow[0, \infty] \text { is an } \mathcal{S} \text { -measurable } \\ \text { function, and } P \text { is an } \mathcal{S} \text { -partition } A_{1}, \ldots, A_{m} \text { of } X . \text { The lower Lebesgue sum } \\ \mathcal{L}(f, P) \text { is defined by } \\ \qquad \mathcal{L}(f, P)=\sum_{j=1}^{m} \mu\left(A_{j}\right) \inf _{A_{j}} f\end{array}$

Comment: I am not sure to understand, how do you define the lebesgue integral from there ? Your question is the only thing that shows up for lower Lebesgue sum

Comment: I have then define the integral by $\int f d \mu=\sup \{\mathcal{L}(f, P): P \text { is an } \mathcal{S} \text { -partition of } X\}$

Comment: Well in you post you use $\sup$ instead of $\inf$, if it is the question, the answer is negative imagine a finite set with a partition where each class contains 2 elements, and the $\sigma$-algebra is defined by intersections and union of those sets. Then your two sums will diverge if you take a function that is $\infty$ on one of the two points for each class and $0$ for the other one